# How to jump to source from output console in PyCharm?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

Looking for a way to have an ability to jump to a line in code by clicking some output line in console (similar to eclipse functionality)
My current output looks like this:

```
C:\anaconda3\python.exe C:/test/TestUnit.py 
2018-06-01 10:43:26,610 TestUnit.py              <module>() 8    INFO     TestUnit started, checking input params ...
2018-06-01 10:43:26,610 TestUnit.py              <module>() 27   INFO     Provided video file: [D:\input\video.mp4]
2018-06-01 10:43:26,613 Video.py                getFrames() 4    INFO     Extracting frames from input video D:\input\video.mp4
```

Is it possible to be able to click on getFrames() and have IDE jumping to file video.py => relevant code line in getFrames() function ?

which looks like this:

```
class Video(object):
 def getFrames(video,log):
   log.info("Extracting frames from input video " + video) <<====== jump to this
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `Ctrl+Mouse left click` on target function

Comment: In my IDE PyCharm console, printed output is a plain text, means  not clickable, With Ctrl+Mouse left click it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old question for everybody having the same problem.

The log output needs to include this part:

```
File "/path/to/file.py", line 140
```

Using Python's logging module you can achieve this with

```
format="File \"%(pathname)s\", line %(lineno)d"
```

Here is a complete example of the logging config

```
logging.basicConfig(level=10, format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [File \"%(pathname)s\", line %(lineno)d] %(message)s", datefmt="%H:%M:%S", stream=sys.stdout)
```